# SharePoint 2019 Monitoring in SCOM

Tags: monitoring, 2019, scom

Not sure if this is the correct forum for this, but I am having an issue monitoring SharePoint 2019 in my existing SCOM instance because the SharePoint 2016 Management Pack blocks the install of the SharePoint 2019 Management Pack.  Has anyone else seen this?  Is there a workaround?  I need to be able to use both management packs in the same SCOM instance (unless the 2019 pack will monitor SharePoint 2016) and this hasn't been a problem with the previous MPs (SharePoint 2010/2013/2016 MPs are installed side-by-side in SCOM and working fine).

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing, it would appear that the SharePoint 2019 Management Pack will discover and monitor 2016 farms as well.